# Normalize heavily merged excel table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I was asked to do some data manipulation on an excel table with a head that's heavily merged as in the following picture...

[image: Merge Problem]

**And here is the some of the data inside the table...**

[image: Table Data]
If I tried to drop the first 17 rows of the head to drop the nonsense and get to the column names it still wouldn't read the column names correctly due to current merge, and I couldn't seem to figure a way to do it using pandas yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry had to re-upload the image, its up now.

Comment: ur target is row 18?  try reading that exact line: pd.read_excel(filename, header=17)

Comment: what is below row 18?

Comment: I actually ran into this problem as well couple of times, couldn't find a straightforward solution.

Comment: My problem is with the merge not actually reaching the correct header.

Comment: What's below 18 is normal values for each column name/type.

Comment: if u dont mind, could you show what it looks like when u read just from 18? could u also just show what the excel file looks like for a couple of rows after 18

Comment: Ok, it's in the question body now.